# Using XState extension in VSCode to edit state machine but the code is not updating accordingly

Tags: typescript, state-machine, xstate, xstate-react

I am using the Stately's state machine library called [XState](https://stately.ai/docs/xstate) in my React(Typescript) project.

There is an [official extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=statelyai.stately-vscode) called "XState" for VSCode, so, I installed it.

After that, I wrote the initial code to create my state machine, then from the VSCode I can open the "visual editor" by clicking this:

[image]

It opens the XState visual editor in VSCode, but when I update the state machine visual diagram, the typescript code is not updating accordingly:

[image]

Then I go to the extension & noticed there are some error logs:

[image]

I tried rebooting VSCode, but that doesn't help.  Anybody encountered this issue? How to solve it so that I can see live updating on code while I am editing the state machine diagram in editor?

Comment: Same issue here. Seems to be stuck in a broken state. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an `id` to the machine first. Sorry, this is a tricky bug on our end!